# How can I get my location with Kotlin dev Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, location

I'm making a [Google Maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Maps) app. I've put on the API key, and the default code runs without any problems, but I don't know how to localize my position...

I looked around and found this document:

[Kotlin API](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/location/package-summary)

But still when I try to import:

```
import com.google.android.location.Location
```

the first "location" will appear in red... It looks like this API document is deprecated, so I don't know what to import or use to build my app...

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code for getting the current location:

#### File *activity_main.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Latitude: "/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lonTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Longitude: "/>

</LinearLayout>
```

#### File *MainActivity.kt*

```
import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import android.location.LocationManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Looper
import android.provider.Settings
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.google.android.gms.location.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val PERMISSION_ID = 42
    lateinit var mFusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)

        getLastLocation()
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun getLastLocation() {
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            if (isLocationEnabled()) {

                mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    var location: Location? = task.result
                    if (location == null) {
                        requestNewLocationData()
                    } else {
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = location.latitude.toString()
                        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = location.longitude.toString()
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        } else {
            requestPermissions()
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun requestNewLocationData() {
        var mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.interval = 0
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 0
        mLocationRequest.numUpdates = 1

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        mFusedLocationClient!!.requestLocationUpdates(
            mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback,
            Looper.myLooper()
        )
    }

    private val mLocationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult) {
            var mLastLocation: Location = locationResult.lastLocation
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.latTextView).text = mLastLocation.latitude.toString()
            findViewById<TextView>(R.id.lonTextView).text = mLastLocation.longitude.toString()
        }
    }

    private fun isLocationEnabled(): Boolean {
        var locationManager: LocationManager = getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) || locationManager.isProviderEnabled(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER
        )
    }

    private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }


    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                getLastLocation()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

See here for more details: *[Getting Current Location (latitude, longitude) in Android using Kotlin](https://www.androdocs.com/kotlin/getting-current-location-latitude-longitude-in-android-using-kotlin.html)*

Comment: I haved many errors with this code but still i think you gave me the solution ! I will try and paste working code. Brb ! =)

Comment: What is the errors? See that site that I linked to. You should add some permissions to manifest.@framb axa