# setValue Data To Firebase RealTimeDatabase in Foreground Service Not Writing Data

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, foreground-service

I have Created a Standard Foreground Service and Tried to Implement setValue It is not causing any errors but the realtime database isn't updated, although the Toast "Yay" prints which means there is no issue in the OnCreate Method so the problem must be with the Implementation of Database Reference, My final goal is to use live location Latitude Longitude so If there is anything relevent which would help me setValue in RTD would be really Helpful, Thanks

```
public class ForegroundService extends Service {
private static final String LOG_TAG = "ForegroundService";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    DatabaseReference db= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Coor");
    db.child("ysssss").push().child("WORKED").setValue("YAY");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Yay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

/*Standard Foreground onStartCommand: 
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {*/
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971836/how-can-i-get-my-location-with-kotlin-dev-android/60972122#60972122

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60896895/kotlin-and-firebase-read-and-write-data/60896995#60896995

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Thank you for the help with the location coordinates, I am not experienced in Kotlin but will try to make sense of it in Java, Also could you help with the setValue issue I am having? Thanks :)

Comment: Are you trying to update an existing value or create a new value? Please post a screenshot of your database structure also then I will definitely help you :-) I can help you with pushing data to database but not with location part

Comment: @Dharmaraj Thank you for your reply,I have an empty data tree, I have just added a Child Coor in case the issue was it not adding a tree, I will update my question with a screenshot

Comment: Yeah sure, screenshots may help. and just say me what data you want to update in the database. Post code of that data to so that I can post a code which can post the data directly in the database

Comment: By the way, onCreate method will make sure the code runs everytime so the data gets updated on every app restart? You want the data to be updated on every app restart??

Comment: @Dharmaraj In the code I have uploaded I am just testing if it uploads a hard-coded text "ysssss" which a push child under that a child "WORKED" with value "YAY"

Comment: @Dharmaraj I am Talking about Foreground Activity do I want it constantly in the foreground

Comment: So you constantly want to update data right ?? every second the app is open ?

Comment: Please try my posted answer once and show me the output. We will modify it as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

First of all create a java class named `updateData.java`

**updateData.java**:

```
public class updatedata {

    private String myData;
public updateData() {
}

public String getmyData() {
    return myData;
}

public void setmyData(String myData) {
    this.myData = myData;
}
//These are getters and setters.
```

Now in your **MainActivity**

```
DatabaseReference dRef;    
updateData mUpdateData;

dRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Coor");

mUpdateData.setmyData("YAY");
dRef.child("WORKED").setValue(updateData);
```

This is like a general code. Can you please try executing this by replacing with your own variable and data? Let me know if you need any modification.

Comment: Hi Thank You For Your Post, I don't have a problem with a setValue in the MainActivity or During the Application is not destroyed, I need it during the foreground service, Although I did try your code I am having the same results, Thank You

Comment: @Anonymous can you explain more what do you mean by the foreground service?